# Loading data before AppComponent.ngOnInit is called

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-httpclient, angular-resolver

In my Angular 8 project, I have a `UserService` that requests the current `User` from the server using `HttpClient` and asynchronously assigns the response to its public `user` field. I inject a `UserService` into `AppComponent` and in its `ngOnInit` I copy `this.userService.user` into its own `user` field, which is bound to the content of a `span` defined in its HTML template file. In order to force Angular finish loading the `User` before `ngOnInit` is called, I implemented the `Resolve<User>` interface in `UserService` and set it as the resolver of the root route ("").

My problem is that when the application is started, `AppComponent.ngOnInit` is called *before* the router is activated and the resolver loads the `User` from the server, so `AppComponent` cannot display the loaded `User` in its HTML. **Is it possible to load data before the bootstrapped component (`AppComponent`) is loaded, that is, before its `ngOnInit` method is called?**

Comment: Did you use a route Guard ? Did you try to use RxJS Subject to get user ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun No, I don't use route guards. And no, I don't use RxJS Subject - I implemented Resolve<User>.resolve() in UserService, which does load the User when the router is activated. The problem is that the router is activated only after AppComponent is loaded.

Comment: I support @ibenjelloun comment, easiest way to handle this is to subscribe in your `OnInit` hook on an Observable bound to user request, not to force Angular to wait the answer of an asynchronous call to load your `AppComponent` .

Comment: @Mozgor Thanks, in the end, I "embraced the async way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with APP_INITIALIZER, a function that will be executed before an application is initialized

> https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

In your app.module.ts

```
export function initializeConfig(initService: InitService) {
  const x = (): Promise<any> => {
    return initService.Init();
  };
  return x;
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    InitService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeConfig,
      deps: [InitService],
      multi: true
    },
  ],
  ...
})
```

init.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class InitService {

  constructor(private service: YourService) {
  }

  Init() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.service.loadDataBeforeBootstrap.then( () => {
        resolve();
      }).catch( error => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What is initializeConfig?